# Loading OpenID provider logo icons on a slow connection

Tags: feature-request, openid, login

I've just tried to log in to Careers on my iPhone with a rather slow connection. This meant I had to wait while Safari loaded all the OpenID provider logo icons before I could choose the correct one.

Could there be text links, as well as image links, so that I can start logging in sooner?